# Is it possible to write a function that would take any macro and turn it into a function so that it can be passed as an argument to another function?

Tags: macros, scheme, racket

AND and OR are macros and since macros aren't first class in scheme/racket they cannot be passed as arguments to other functions. A partial solution is to use and-map or or-map. Is it possible to write a function that would take arbitrary macro and turn it into a function so that it can be passed as an argument to another function? Are there any languages that have first class macros?

Answer (score 6):

In general, no. Consider that `let` is (or could be) implemented as a macro on top of `lambda`:

```
(let ((x 1))
  (foo x))
```

could be a macro that expands to

```
((lambda (x) (foo x)) 1)
```

Now, what would it look like to convert `let` to a function? Clearly it is nonsense.  What would its inputs be? Its return value?

Many macros will be like this. In fact, any macro that could be routinely turned into a function without losing any functionality is a bad macro! Such a macro should have been a function to begin with.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @amalloy. If something is written as a macro, it probably does something that functions can't do (e.g., introduce bindings, change evaluation order). So automatically converting arbitrary macro into a function is a really bad idea even if it is possible.

> Is it possible to write a function that would take arbitrary macro and turn it into a function so that it can be passed as an argument to another function?

No, but it is somewhat doable to write a *macro* that would take *some* macro and turn it into a function.

```
#lang racket

(require (for-syntax racket/list))

(define-syntax (->proc stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ mac #:arity arity)
     (with-syntax ([(args ...) (generate-temporaries (range (syntax-e #'arity)))])
       #'(λ (args ...) (mac args ...)))]))

((->proc and #:arity 2) 42 12)
(apply (->proc and #:arity 2) '(#f 12))
((->proc and #:arity 2) #f (error 'not-short-circuit))
```

You might also be interested in [identifier macro](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/pattern-macros.html?q=identifier%20macro#%28tech._identifier._macro%29), which allows us to use an identifier as a macro in some context and function in another context. This could be used to create a first class `and`/`or` which short-circuits when it's used as a macro, but could be passed as a function value in non-transformer position.

On the topic of first class macro, take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fexpr. It's known to be a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

Not in the way you probably expect

To see why, here is a way of thinking about macros:  A macro is a function which takes a bit of source code and turns it into another bit of source code: the expansion of the macro.  In other words a macro is a function whose domain and range are *source code*.

Once the source code is fully expanded, then it's fed to either an evaluator or a compiler.  Let's assume it's fed to a compiler because it makes the question easier to answer: a compiler itself is simply a function whose domain is source code and whose range is some sequence of instructions for a machine (which may or may not be a real machine) to execute.  Those instructions might include things like 'call this function on these arguments'.

So, what you are asking is: can the 'this function' in 'call this function on these arguments' be some kind of macro?  Well, yes, it could be, but whatever source code it is going to transform certainly can not be the source code of the program you are executing, because that is gone: all that's left is the sequence of instructions that was the return value of the compiler.

So you might say: OK, let's say we disallow compilers: can we do it now?  Well, leaving aside that 'disallowing compilers' is kind of a serious limitation, this was, in fact, something that very old dialects of Lisp sort-of did, using a construct called a [FEXPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fexpr), as mentioned in another answer.  It's important to realise that *FEXPRs existed because people had not yet invented macros*.  Pretty soon, people did invent macros, and although FEXPRs and macros coexisted for a while – mostly because people had written code which used FEXPRs which they wanted to keep running, and because writing macros was a serious pain before things like backquote existed – FEXPRs died out.  And they died out because they were semantically horrible: even by the standards of 1960s Lisps they were semantically horrible.

Here's one small example of why FEXPRs are so horrible:  Let's say I write this function in a language with FEXPRs:

```
(define (foo f g x)
  (apply f (g x)))
```

Now: *what happens when I call `foo`*?  In particular, *what happens if `f` might be a FEXPR?*.  Well, the answer is that I can't compile `foo` at all: I have to wait until run-time and make some on-the-fly decision about what to do.

Of course this isn't what these old Lisps with FEXPRs probably did: they would just silently have assumed that `f` was a normal function (which they would have called an EXPR) and compiled accordingly (and yes, even very old Lisps had compilers).  If you passed something which was a FEXPR you just lost: either the thing detected that, or more likely it fall over horribly or gave you some junk answer.

And this kind of horribleness is why macros were invented: macros provide a semantically sane approach to processing Lisp code which allows (eventually, this took a long time to actually happen) minor details like compilation being possible at all, code having reasonable semantics and compiled code having the same semantics as interpreted code.  These are features people like in their languages, it turns out.

---

Incidentally, in both Racket and Common Lisp, macros are explicitly functions.  In Racket they are functions which operate on special 'syntax' objects because that's how you get hygiene, but in Common Lisp, which is much less hygienic, they're just functions which operate on CL source code, where the source code is simply made up of lists, symbols &c.

Here's an example of this in Racket:

```
> (define foo (syntax-rules ()
                [(_ x) x]))
> foo
#<procedure:foo>
```

OK, `foo` is now just an ordinary function.  But it's a function whose domain & range are Racket source code: it expects a syntax object as an argument and returns another one:

```
> (foo 1)
; ?: bad syntax
;   in: 1
; [,bt for context]
```

This is because `1` is not a syntax object.

```
> (foo #'(x 1))
#<syntax:readline-input:5:10 1>
> (syntax-e (foo #'(x 1)))
1
```

And in CL this is even easier to see:  Here's a macro definition:

```
(defmacro foo (form) form)
```

And now I can get hold of the macro's function and call it on some CL source code:

```
> (macro-function 'foo)
#<Function foo 4060000B6C>

> (funcall (macro-function 'foo) '(x 1) nil)
1
```

In both Racket and CL, macros are, in fact, first-class (or, in the case of Racket: almost first-class, I think): they are functions which operate on source code, which itself is first-class: you can write Racket and CL programs which construct and manipulate source code in arbitrary ways: that's what macros *are* in these languages.

In the case of Racket I have said 'almost first-class', because I can't see a way, in Racket, to retrieve the function which sits behind a macro defined with `define-syntax` &c.

Comment: I wouldn't say Racket's macros are first class, or at least not at runtime. However, you can retrieve the macro's transformer function at compile time using `syntax-local-value`, but that isn't what determines first-class, at least not the way I think of first-class anyway

Comment: @AlexKnauth: what would you say would make them first class?

Comment: So Fexprs would be first-class because you can theoretically pass them through anywhere you can pass a value and use them afterward, but that is precisely what makes them a bad idea because as you said in your answer they make proper AOT-compilation impossible or garbage.

Comment: @AlexKnauth: I'm pretty sure fexprs were not really first-class in any Lisp that used them historically in practice: I'm no longer completely sure but I think that `apply` or `funcall` simply assumed that its argument was not a fexpr.  I think the thing that would make Racket's macros first-class would be if you had access to their definitions as functions at runtime so you could tease apart macro expansion the way you can in CL, rather than just having `expand` or whatever which does everything.

Comment: A macro *is not* a function, but a macro *has* a (compile-time) function. And I agree with @AlexKnauth: macros are not first class. You cannot pass them to functions, return them from functions, or store them in data structures. (In Racket, a macro defined at phase N is a special kind of entry in the phase-N environment that points to a phase-N+1 function. That function is a first class value in phase N+1, but the macro is not first class in phase N, and it doesn't exist in any other phase, so it can't be first class there either.)

Comment: @RyanCulpepper: Yes, so I think my 'almost first-class' is OK.

Answer (score 0):

I've created something like this in Scheme, it's macro that return lambda that use eval to execute the macro:

```lisp
(define-macro (macron m)
   (let ((x (gensym)))
     `(lambda (,x)
         (eval `(,',m ,@,x)))))
```

Example usage:

```lisp
;; normal eval
(define x (map (lambda (x)
                 (eval `(lambda ,@x)))
               '(((x) (display x)) ((y) (+ y y)))))

;; using macron macro
(define x (map (macron lambda)
               '(((x) (display x)) ((y) (+ y y)))))
```

and `x` in both cases is list of two functions.

another example:

```lisp
(define-macro (+++ . args)
   `(+ ,@args))

((macron +++) '(1 2 3))
```